# Show that the number of elements in the equivalence class is n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Question is :

Let $G$ be a finiote group of order n = $p^{\alpha}$m, where $p$ is a prime number and if $p^r$ | m  but $p^{r+1} \nmid$ m

Let $\mathcal M$ be the set of all subset of $G$ which have $p^{\alpha}$ elements . Then $\mathcal M$ has elements $\left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
m p^{\alpha}\\ 
p^{\alpha}
\end{array} 
\right) $. Given $M_1,M_2$ $\in \mathcal M$, define $M_1 \thicksim M_2$ if there exist g $\in G$ such that $M_1 = M_2$g. This is an equivalence relation. there is at least one equivalence class of elements in $\mathcal M$ such that number of elements in this class is not multiple of $p^{r+1}$, for if $p^{r+1}$ is a divisor of the size of each equivalence class , then $p^{r+1}$ would be a divisor of of the number of elements in $\mathcal M$. Since $\mathcal M$ has $\left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
m p^{\alpha}\\ 
p^{\alpha}
\end{array} 
\right) $.  and $\ \ p^{r+1} \nmid \left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
m p^{\alpha}\\ 
p^{\alpha}
\end{array} 
\right) $. , this cannot be the case.

**Show that the number of elements in this equivalence class is n ?**

Comment: I don't quite understand: If we let $M$ denote such a class for which $p^{r+1}$ doesn't divide its size, then you are meant to show  that the size of $M$ is $n$? But if $\alpha\ge 1$ then $p^{r+1}$ divides $n=|M|$, contradiction...

Comment: It seems that the number of elements in that equivalent class should be $m$ not $n$.

Comment: It seems to be that $\;\alpha\;$ must be $\;r\;$ ...or the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, Whatever I was reading syllow theorem in I.N HERSTIEN book. There are given three proof of the result **If $p$ is a prime number and $ \ \ p^{\alpha}|o(G)$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^{\alpha}$**, one of the proof is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703768/if-p-is-a-prime-number-and-p-alphaog-then-g-has-a-subgroup-of/703804?noredirect=1#703804. I have stuck in this proof.

Comment: Please clear my doubts